# Using ChipDrawable in TextInputEditText span, how do I add clickListener to the ChipDrawable CloseIcon?

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable, android-textinputedittext, android-chips

I have following scenario:

Chip definition:

```
<chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_house_24"
    android:text="@string/chips_holder"
    app:closeIconEnabled="true"
    />
```

section of xml containing a TextInputTeditText:

```
...
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:hint="Gallery Selections"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_gallery_text_input_edit_text_selections"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
...
```

a room liveData result observer which provides data from a set of variables:

```
...
liveDataFilterGallery?.observe(
    viewLifecycleOwner
){filterGalleryResult->
    filterGalleryResult?.let { safeFilterGalleryResult->
        safeFilterGalleryResult.apply {
            val prefixes = arrayOf(
                "Site No",
                "Farm No",
                "Site Id",
                "Assignment Id",
                "Category",
                "Time Stamp")
            fragmentGalleryTextInputEditTextSelections.setText(
                (if(siteNo.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${prefixes[0]} = '$siteNo';") +
                (if(farmNo.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${prefixes[1]} = '$farmNo';") +
                (if(siteId.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${prefixes[2]} = '$siteId';") +
                (if(assignmentId.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${prefixes[3]} = '$assignmentId';") +
                (if(category.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${prefixes[4]} = '$category';") +
                (if(timeStamp.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${prefixes[5]} = '$timeStamp';"))
            setEntryChips(fragmentGalleryTextInputEditTextSelections.text!!)
        }
    }
}
...
```

A function `setEntryChips` which creates chips and uses `spannable` to "replace" text with this ChipDrawable. Searches editables for `;` and creates chips upon that. (The `;` is addded through a selection function and replacing function not shown here.)

```
private fun setEntryChips(editable: Editable)
{
    var position = 0
    Log.i(TAG, "setEntryChips: editable.length = ${editable.length}")
    Log.i(TAG, "setEntryChips: editable = '$editable'")
    if(editable.isNotEmpty()) {
        editable.split(';').mapIndexed { index, string ->
            Log.i(TAG, "setEntryChips: split='$string'")
            Log.i(TAG, "setEntryChips: index=$index")
            if(string.isEmpty()) return@mapIndexed
            val chipDrawable =
                ChipDrawable.createFromResource(requireContext(), R.xml.input_selection_chip)
            chipDrawable.text = string
            chipDrawable.setBounds(
                0,
                0,
                chipDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
                chipDrawable.intrinsicHeight
            )
            val span = ImageSpan(chipDrawable)
            editable.setSpan(
                span,
                position,
                position + string.length,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
            position += string.length+1
            /*
            val chip = Chip(requireContext())
            chip.setChipDrawable(chipDrawable)
            chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener {
                Log.i(TAG, "setEntryChips: closeIcon clicked = $string")
            }
            */
            Log.i(TAG, "setEntryChips: it.length = ${string.length}")
            Log.i(TAG, "setEntryChips: position  = $position")
        }
    }
    
}
```

My suggestion to wrap the `chipDrawable` into a `Chip` view programmatically fails, because the chip disappear from the `TextInputEditText`, and therefore is no valid solution.

How do I add a `clickListener` to the `closeIcon` then, and keep the chip visible in the `TextInputEditText` view ?

RG